# India domestic flights to carry same baggage as international flights

Tags: luggage, india, international-travel, domestic-travel, connecting-flights

I am planing to book ticket from `IAH(Houston, TX, USA)` to `BOM(Mumbai, MH, INDIA)`. My final destination is `AMD(Ahmedabad, GJ, INDIA)`.

I did this before, booked domestic flights from `AMD` to `BOM` and change airport @ `BOM` and then catch international flights. [GoAir](https://www.goair.in/terms-conditions) has policy `For Customers travelling on an International flight`. Its still there on their `Terms and Condition Page`, If you have internation flights in 24 hours of the `GoAir` flights, then they will carry same luggage as internation without any extra baggage charge.

But when I called customer care to verify this, they told, its there in website, but now they are not supporting that :(.

I want to know, is there any other carrier in India, which carry same luggage if we have domestic flights in 24 hours of internation flights arrival or departure?

If there is no carrier do this, then which carrier will be cheaper for domestic with luggage ?

I check online, like JetAirways charge `500` Rs per kg, and `GoAir` charges `250` Rs per kg.

This will be expensive for 6 bags with 23 KG each.

Comment: Another thing to consider: If you book the flight from IAH to AMD on one ticket then the international baggage policy will generally apply to the domestic leg as well as the international one.

Comment: @phoog IAH to AMD was costing me 600$ more compare to BOM :(

Comment: If you really have 6 bags of 24kg each, at 250/kg that's 34,500 Rs, with an exchange rate of 62.5RS = $1 makes about $550. (Of course, 500Rs/kg will be double that.) The through ticket at an extra $600 seems possibly wrth while.

Comment: @simonatrcl thanks, I am planing to book a cab for the luggage, it might be cost 10000Rs(180$), just want to check, is there any other airlines like `GoAir` which provide the 2 baggage in domestic flights.